# Performing Split on Pandas dataframe and create a new frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, expand

I have a pandas dataframe with one column like this:

| Merged_Cities |
| --- |
| New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta |
| Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki |
| Paris, Bordeaux, Lyon |
| Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore |
| London, Manchester, Bermingham |

And I want a new dataframe with the output like this:

| Merged_Cities | Cities |
| --- | --- |
| New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta | New York |
| New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta | Wisconsin |
| New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta | Atlanta |
| Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki | Tokyo |
| Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki | Kyoto |
| Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki | Suzuki |
| Paris, Bordeaux, Lyon | Paris |
| Paris, Bordeaux, Lyon | Bordeaux |
| Paris, Bordeaux, Lyon | Lyon |
| Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore | Mumbai |
| Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore | Delhi |
| Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore | Bangalore |
| London, Manchester, Bermingham | London |
| London, Manchester, Bermingham | Manchester |
| London, Manchester, Bermingham | Bermingham |

In short I want to split all the cities into different rows while maintaining the 'Merged_Cities' column.

Here's a replicable version of `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Merged_Cities':['New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta',
                                    'Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki',
                                    'Paris, Bordeaux, Lyon',
                                    'Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore',
                                    'London, Manchester, Bermingham']})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.str.split()` and `.explode()`:

```py
df = df.assign(Cities=df["Merged_Cities"].str.split(", ")).explode("Cities")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                    Merged_Cities      Cities
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta    New York
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta   Wisconsin
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta     Atlanta
1            Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki       Tokyo
1            Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki       Kyoto
1            Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki      Suzuki
2           Paris, Bordeaux, Lyon       Paris
2           Paris, Bordeaux, Lyon    Bordeaux
2           Paris, Bordeaux, Lyon        Lyon
3        Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore      Mumbai
3        Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore       Delhi
3        Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore   Bangalore
4  London, Manchester, Bermingham      London
4  London, Manchester, Bermingham  Manchester
4  London, Manchester, Bermingham  Bermingham
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. However, can you explain if `assign` always matches the size of the `self` argument to the new size of the new column?

Comment: @ArturoSbr [.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas.DataFrame.assign) will create new column in dataframe, so length of the column will be length of the dataframe. Each row contains split string that is afterwards exploded into additional rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is really similar to @AndrejKesely's answer, except it merges `df` and the cities on their index.

```py
# Create pandas.Series from splitting the column on ', '
s = df['Merged_Cities'].str.split(', ').explode().rename('Cities')

# Merge df with s on their index
df = df.merge(s, left_index=True, right_index=True)

# Result
print(df)
                    Merged_Cities      Cities
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta    New York
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta   Wisconsin
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta     Atlanta
1            Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki       Tokyo
1            Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki       Kyoto
                    Merged_Cities      Cities
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta    New York
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta   Wisconsin
0    New York, Wisconsin, Atlanta     Atlanta
1            Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki       Tokyo
1            Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki       Kyoto
1            Tokyo, Kyoto, Suzuki      Suzuki
```